# 404 after upgrading Artifactory Pro

Tags: artifactory

My current version of Artifactory Pro 6.5.2. I can upgrade incrementally from 6.5.2 to 6.5.9 to 6.0.0.  If I try to upgrade beyond 6.0.0, I receive a 404 error when attempting to access Artifactory.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /artifactory/webapp/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
```

I see the following errors in `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logs/catalina/catalina.out`

```
Failed to ensure db table 'master_key_status' exists

Error creating bean with name 'accessJdbcHelperImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize database: Not supported

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/access]]
```

The database I'm using is MySQL

`mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Has any encountered a similar issue when upgrading Artficatory Pro?

Thanks

Comment: I have also encountered the above error while upgrading to version 6.1.0 from 4.9.0. Few points can be please confirm. Any changes in the DB ? i.e migrated the DB from derby to maria. Also the description is not clear. You have upgraded from 6.0.0 to 6.5.2 then to 6.5.9 ?

Comment: My apologies, references to `6.0.0` should be `6.6.0`.

There have been no DB changes.

Comment: Is the DB driver version as per artifactory. Also have you checked the accessibility to maria dB host. I assume the artifactory user exists with privilege to access the table. Worth checking the table in the database with user artifactory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had to update the JDBC driver and add the appropriate `serverTimezone` value to the JDBC url in `db.properties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just marking down the answer.

The issue was with the JDBC driver version of the Maria DB.

One more update done by you was adding the timezone value.